# How to read these expressions: *&pointer VS &*pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

If I have:

```
int j = 8;
int *pointer = &j;
```

then if I do:

```
&*pointer == *&pointer
```

that returns `1` (`true`).

But I have a doubt on the second expression:

1. `&*pointer` returns the address pointed by pointer (first evaluated *
   then &)
2. `*&pointer` returns pointer address and then what it points... but this is the variable not the address. So here is my doubt...

Comment: You doubt is correct because  [precedence of `*` is higher then `&` operators in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) also both have Right-to-left associativity. But In case of `*&pointer` -- `*` can't evaluate fist so it translates to `(&pointer)` then `*` is second operation to perform. But **I guess compiler always optimizes** `*&pointer` and `&*pointer` to `pointer`. (*that is what Edwin Buck's answer says*), you can check with `GCC -S`  option.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Hmm.. not necessarily safe (if we're not talking about naked pointers).  If `pointer` were an iterator for example, `*(&pointer)` would result in an object of type `iterator`, where `&(*pointer)` would result in an object of type `iterator::value_type`.  Just commenting in case a future reader considers to extrapolate the behaviour for naked pointers to things that look like naked pointers but are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pointer` "points" to some address in memory; and it resides at some other address in memory.

```
&*pointer // (*pointer) - dereference `pointer`, now you have `j`
          // &(*pointer) - the address of `j`(that's the data that `pointer` has)
```

Where as:

```
*&pointer //(&pointer) - the address of pointer(where pointer resides in memory)
          // *(&pointer) - deference that address and you get `pointer`
```

---

I *always* find pointers easier to trace with a picture, so maybe this illustration will help to understand why they are the same:

```
//In case of &*pointer, we start with the pointer, the dereference it giving us j
//Then taking the address of that brings us back to pointer:

                                           +--&(*pointer)-----------+
                                           |                        |
memory address            0x7FFF3210       |            0x7FFF0123  |
                        +------------+     |             +-----+    |
data present            | pointer =  | <---+        +->  | j=8 |----+
                        | 0x7FFF0123 | ->(*pointer)-+    +-----+
                        +------------+

//in the *&pointer case, we start with the pointer, take the address of it, then
//dereference that address bring it back to pointer


memory address           +------------>  0x7FFF3210 ----*(&pointer)--+  
                         |                                           |
                         |              +------------+               |   
data present             |              | pointer =  | <----------- -+   
                         +--&pointer ---| 0x7FFF0123 |         
                                        +------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

1. `&*pointer` dereferences the pointer (1. in the diagram below) to give you the `int` object (2.), then takes the address of that object, which of course is the same value as the pointer (1.).

   ```
   ┌─────────┐  ┌───┐
   │ pointer ┿━>│ j │
   └─────────┘  └───┘
       (1.)     (2.)
   ```
2. `*&pointer` takes the address of the pointer (4.) to get a pointer to that pointer (3.), then dereferences that address to get the pointer again (4.).

   ```
   ┌──────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌───┐
   │ &pointer ┿━>│ pointer ┿━>│ j │
   └──────────┘  └─────────┘  └───┘
       (3.)         (4.)
   ```

The important part that you're missing is that `pointer` is the address of the `int` and so `&pointer` is the *address of the address*. Dereferencing you that just gives you the pointer again.

Answer (score 4):

Those expressions are equivalent as long as `pointer` is a raw pointer to a fundamental type (so that `operator &` and `operator *` are **not** overloaded, otherwise the equivalence may not hold).

In fact, this expression:

```
*(&pointer) // Evaluates to the address of j
```

Computes the address of `pointer` first and then dereferences it. This gives again you the *value* of `pointer`, which is the address of `j` (because that's how you initialized `pointer`). This expression, on the other hand:

```
&(*pointer) // Evaluates to the address of j
```

First dereferences `pointer` (giving a reference to `j`) and then takes its address (thus evaluating to the address of `j`).

As you can see, both expressions evaluate to the address of `j`, and therefore they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you generally have much better success reading the type right-to-left

```
 int *pointer = &j;

 (int *) = the pointer to an integer
 (&) = the address of
```

so

```
 (&*) = the pointer to an address of
 (*&) = the address of a pointer
```

Since the address of a pointer is assignable to a pointer (the address of anything is assignable to a pointer), and the pointer to anything is also a pointer, you'll get the assignment to work type-wise, (but I don't think it would be very functional).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You might be correct.  I am really just talking about the type system, and not the compiler implementation; however, if I were building a compiler, you bet I'd optimize what would amount to a no-op out of the output code.

Answer (score 1):

They're identical since nothing else would make sense. `&*pointer` is the address of the object pointed to by `pointer` - and that's the value (the address stored in) `pointer` itself.

`*&pointer` is the object pointed to by the address of `pointer` (the address of the `pointer` variable dereferenced) - again, that's `pointer` itself.

Answer (score 1):

> `*&pointer` returns pointer address and then what it points... but this is the variable not the address. So here is my doubt...

Let's take this one step at a time:

- `&pointer` is of type `int**` and points to the `pointer` variable.
- `*&pointer` dereferences the above, being in effect equivalent to simply `pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

`&*pointer` is `&(*pointer)` and returns the address of the value that `pointer` points to, or `pointer`.

`*&pointer` is `*(&pointer)` and returns the value that `&pointer` points to, or `pointer`.

Comment: I think compiler always optimizes `*&pointer` and `&*pointer` to `pointer` ..can please read my comment to OP question. and let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Just checked with the C standard, `*` isn't evaluated in `&*pointer`. That may be a little more complicated in C++, though, but still the result is the same for the code given in the question. Where did I get that...